# How to do the share extension to show the http shares and not the https?

Tags: php, facebook, joomla, meta-tags, joomla-extensions

I have this situations on Facebook Object Debugger:

This one is if I input the http link

[image: http Input]

and this one for https link

[image: https Input URL]

The code of my joomla extension is:

```
<?php

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
# mod_ofblikebutton - Optimized Facebook Like Button
#    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

# author:    Optimized Sense
# copyright: Copyright (C) 2013 http://www.o-sense.com. All Rights Reserved.
# @license: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
# Websites: http://www.o-sense.com
# Technical Support:  http://www.o-sense.com/contact-us/support-inquiries.html
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
class oFBLikeButton{
    function getData(&$params ){        
        $oFBLinkTitle   = 'O-Sense';
        $oFBLink    = 'http://www.o-sense.com';
        //$oFBLinkImg = 'http://www.o-sense.com/osensecopy.png';
        //$oFlink   = $params->get('olink');///
        $oFBLink = JURI::current();
        $oFshowSend = $params->get('oshowSend');///
        $oFstyle    = $params->get('ostyle');
        $oFwidth    = $params->get('owidth', '400');///
        $oFfaces    = $params->get('ofaces');///        
        $oFfont = $params->get('ofont');///
        $oFcolor    = $params->get('ocolor');///
        $oFverb = $params->get('overb');///
        $oFsource   = $params->get('osource');///
        $oFlang     = $params->get('olang');///
        if($oFfaces == '1'){
            $oFfaces    = 'true';
        }else{
            $oFfaces    = 'false';
        }
        if($oFshowSend == '1'){
            $oFshowSend = 'true';
        }else{
            $oFshowSend = 'false';
        }
        $data ='';
        if($oFsource == '1'){
            //HTML5 

            $app = JFactory::getApplication();

            $menu = $app->getMenu();

            $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
            $fburl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

            if($fburl == 'https://www.atlantotec.com/de/' || $fburl == 'https://www.atlantotec.com' || $fburl == 'https://www.atlantotec.com/de')

            {
                $pageurl = 'http://www.atlantotec.com/de/';
                $spageurl = 'https://www.atlantotec.com/de/';

            } else { 

                $finalurls = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                $urls = '';
                foreach ($finalurls as $finalurl){

                    if($finalurl != ''){

                        $urls .= '/'.$finalurl;

                    }

                }

                if ($lang->getTag() == 'it-IT') {
                    $pageurl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$urls;

                    $spageurl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$urls;
                } else {
                    $pageurl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$urls;

                    $spageurl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$urls;

                }

            }
            $data = '<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {

  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=541263185976160";

  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>';

            $data = $data . '<div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$pageurl.'" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>';

            /*$url = 'http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls='.$pageurl.','.$spageurl;

            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            $retrun = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($retrun);
            $total_count=0;

            foreach($oXML->link_stat as $link_stat){

                //if($total_count != $link_stat->total_count || $total_count ==0)

                $total_count += $link_stat->total_count; 

            }*/

            /*$data = '<div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$spageurl.'" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>';

            $data = '<div id="fb-root"></div><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/'.$oFlang.'/all.js#xfbml=1";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>';

            $data = $data.'<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
                                                                                           document.write(\'<div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$pageurl.'" data-width="'.$oFwidth.'" data-colorscheme="'.$oFcolor.'" data-show-faces="'.$oFfaces.'" data-send="'.$oFshowSend.'" data-font="'.$oFfont.'" data-action="'.$oFverb.'" data-layout="button"></div><div class="pluginCountButton pluginCountNum"><div class="pluginCountButtonNub"><s></s><i></i></div><span id="fb-count">'.$total_count.'</span></div> \'); 
                                                                                           //]]>
            </script>              <div style="display:none; position: relative; height: 15px; width: 100%; font-size: 10px; color: #808080; font-weight: normal; font-family: \'lucida grande\',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; line-height: 1.28; text-align: right; direction: ltr;"><a href="'.$pageurl.'" target="_blank" style="color: #808080;"> <img alt="OSense" src="'.$oFBLinkImg.'" style="visibility:visible; zoom: 1; opacity: 1; vertical-align: text-top;" />  '.$oFBLinkTitle.'</a></div>';*/

            /*$data = $data.'<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
                                                                                           document.write(\'<div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$spageurl.'" data-width="'.$oFwidth.'" data-colorscheme="'.$oFcolor.'" data-show-faces="'.$oFfaces.'" data-send="'.$oFshowSend.'" data-font="'.$oFfont.'" data-action="'.$oFverb.'" data-layout="'.$oFstyle.'"></div> \'); 

               //]]>

            </script>              <div style="display:none; position: relative; height: 15px; width: 100%; font-size: 10px; color: #808080; font-weight: normal; font-family: \'lucida grande\',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; line-height: 1.28; text-align: right; direction: ltr;"><a href="'.$spageurl.'" target="_blank" style="color: #808080;"> <img alt="OSense" src="'.$oFBLinkImg.'" style="visibility:visible; zoom: 1; opacity: 1; vertical-align: text-top;" />  '.$oFBLinkTitle.'</a></div>';*/

        }else if($oFsource == '2'){
            //XFBML
            $data = '<div id="fb-root"></div><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/'.$oFlang.'/all.js#xfbml=1";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>';

            $data = $data.'<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
               document.write(\'<fb:like href="'.$oFlink.'" width="'.$oFwidth.'" colorscheme="'.$oFcolor.'" show_faces="'.$oFfaces.'" font="'.$oFfont.'" send="'.$oFshowSend.'" layout="'.$oFstyle.'" action="'.$oFverb.'"></fb:like> \'); 

               //]]>
            </script>           <div style="display:none; position: relative; height: 15px; width: 100%; font-size: 10px; color: #808080; font-weight: normal; font-family: \'lucida grande\',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; line-height: 1.28; text-align: right; direction: ltr;"><a href="'.$oFBLink.'" target="_blank" style="color: #808080;"> <img alt="OSense" src="'.$oFBLinkImg.'" style="visibility:visible; zoom: 1; opacity: 1; vertical-align: text-top;" />  '.$oFBLinkTitle.'</a></div>';
        }else { 
            //iFrame            

            $oFsource   ="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=".$oFlang."&amp;href=".$oFlink."&amp;width=".$oFwidth .
                    "&amp;colorscheme=".$oFcolor."&amp;show_faces=".$oFfaces .

                    "&amp;send=".$oFshowSend."&amp;layout=".$oFstyle."&amp;font=".$oFfont."&amp;action=".$oFverb."&amp;height=26";

            $data = '<iframe src="'.$oFsource.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:'.$oFwidth.'px; height:26px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>      <div style="display:none; position: relative; height: 15px; width: 100%; font-size: 10px; color: #808080; font-weight: normal; font-family: \'lucida grande\',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif; line-height: 1.28; text-align: right; direction: ltr;"><a href="'.$oFBLink.'" target="_blank" style="color: #808080;"> <img alt="OSense" src="'.$oFBLinkImg.'" style="visibility:visible; zoom: 1; opacity: 1; vertical-align: text-top;" />  '.$oFBLinkTitle.'</a></div>';

        }


        return $data;

    }
}
```

And the .httaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
# HTTPS Redirect

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.atlantotec\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.atlantotec.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)=it$ http://www.atlantotec.com/it/$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)=de$ http://www.atlantotec.com/de/$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)=en$ http://www.atlantotec.com/en/$1 [R,NC]
```

What I want to do is to share http link and to show the shares from http link, in this moment I can share the http link, but I see the https shares.

In Facebook Object Debugger you can see if I check the http link I see the https shares, if I check the https link I see the http shares.

I deleted already the canonical tag but doesn't work if you think that is an option.

So how to share http and see http shares not https?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your website, and the main issue with your website is that you are redirecting from http to https, but, the og:url is set to the http:// version. Check the HTML code and you will see this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.[yourdomain].com"/>
```

This is confusing Facebook, you should have the og:url as http when you are in http mode, and as https whe you are in https mode.

PS: I still see this in the code...

```
<link href="/de/" rel="canonical" />
```

...but I don't think it's harmful.

Comment: My website is only in https mode now. And I want to share the http mode and show the http mode on the website. I want facebook to see me only as http mode.

Comment: @focusoft: If your site is redirecting everything to HTTPS automatically, but you want Facebook to use the HTTP version of your URLs – then you must not automatically redirect to HTTPS, when the FB scraper requests them, but let it read the necessary meta data from the HTTP URL. The FB Scaper [can be identified by its User Agent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo) – so add an exception to your HTTP->HTTPS rewriting based on that.

Comment: @CBroe you mean to add a rule in .httaccess ?

Comment: If your redirect is configured in there, then yes.

Comment: I will try and I will let you know if it's working. I edit the question and I will add the actual .httaccess code too.

Comment: @CBroe I added a exception for facebook scraper but still not working.

Comment: Right now, the debug tool says it can’t read your URL at all. Looks like your site is doing an automatic redirect back to itself, this happens in the browser as well. Usually people use to that to set a cookie on the first request, and then have that cookie available when the same URL is requested again because of the redirect – and that can of course fail, if the client does not support cookies.