# Can I show a facebook share counter of my website on other website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

Simple question:

I want to show a facebook share counter from site1.com on site2.com

[image: Share count]

I think I must to do some changes to data-layout="button_count" . But how to do that?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Why you tag PHP?

Comment: Well, here's the manual and the configurator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Comment: @insertusernamehere I don't want to share I only want to show the count.

Comment: @Hassaan I edited the question. Also check my other question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34141378/how-to-do-the-share-extension-to-show-the-http-shares-and-not-the-https)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to display the share count send a request to

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[URL]
```

It will respond with a JSON object that you can then parse using JavaScript or PHP.

If called like: `http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.stackoverflow.com` it will return:

```
{
    "id": "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "shares": 36267,
    "comments": 4
}
```

**Example in PHP**

As the question was tagged PHP as well here's an example:

```
$x = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.stackoverflow.com') );
print $x->shares; // 36267
```

Comment: I just edited my question, please check what I want to show.

Comment: @focusoft See the example code I've added to my answer. With this code you can get the current amount of shares and you can output it anywhere and in any format you want. This works similar if you're using Javascript.